# Generic Parameter 'C' could not be inferred, Cannot convert value of type '[ApiMovieStruct]' to expected argument type 'Binding<C>'

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have a data class that shows:

```
import SwiftUI
 

struct ApiMovieStruct: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
   
    var poster_path: String
    var overview: String
    var release_date: String
    var id: String
    var title: String

}
```

and I keep getting these errors from this view

```
struct SearchApiList: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(foundMoviesList) { aMovie in
                NavigationLink(destination: SearchApiDetails(movie: aMovie)) {
                    SearchApiItems(movie: aMovie)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Search Results"), displayMode: .inline)
    }
}

struct SearchApiList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SearchApiList()
    }
}
```

On the line ForEach(foundMoviesList) there is an error I get where: Generic Parameter 'C' could not be inferred, Cannot convert value of type '[ApiMovieStruct]' to expected argument type 'Binding'

Do you guys know why this is happening?
foundMoviesList can be found below, there is more code, but I think this might be enough. Thank you all.

````
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

// Global array of API Recipe structs
var foundMoviesList = [ApiMovieStruct]()

fileprivate var previousQuery = ""

public func obtainDataFromApi(apiQueryUrl: String) {
    
    // Avoid executing this function if already done for the same query URL
    if apiQueryUrl == previousQuery {
        return
    } else {
        previousQuery = apiQueryUrl
    }
    
    // Clear out previous content in the global array
    foundMoviesList = [ApiMovieStruct]()
    ```
````

Comment: This is not reproducible. Please try to add an [mre]. Please add `SearchApiDetails` and `SearchApiItems`.